# Is it possible to call for mouse movements without MOUSEEVENT's using SendInput?

Tags: c++, mouseevent, sendinput

Im trying to get a mouse to move without using MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE to control recoil in a gun for a videogame. The code I have now is this. Is this even possible and if so any feedback would be great.

```
    int x_ = 0, y_ = 0, t_ = 0;
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= (int)control_time; ++i) { 
        
        INPUT input;
        input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        int xI = i * x / (int)control_time;
        int yI = i * y / (int)control_time;
        int tI = i * (int)control_time / (int)control_time;
        input.mi.mouseData = 0;
        input.mi.mouseData = 0;
        input.mi.dx = (int)xI - (int)x_;
        input.mi.dy = (int)yI - (int)y_;
        input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
        pQuerySleep((int)tI - (int)t_);
        x_ = xI; y_ = yI; t_ = tI;

    }
    pQuerySleep((int)delay - (int)control_time);
}
```

Comment: If your quesiton is "How do I do X without the tool for doing X", you should probably explain why that tool is inadequate.

Comment: the reason its inadequate because the game im making the recoil control for can see MOUSEEVENTS, im looking for another way to do simulate mouse events without this method

Comment: @Thomas that is not a very helpful description.